# Sharing variable without synchronization

Tags: java, concurrency

I read it from *Java Concurrency in Practice*, that it is bad to share variables in threads without synchronisation. However, for some examples as following which only have one read thread and one write thread, I can't find errors in it. From my perspective, the result for the following program will definitely terminate and print 42 because ReaderThread can go through only when ready becomes true, and that means number is 42. Could somebody give me some explanation why I am wrong?

```
public class NoVisibility {
    private static boolean ready;
    private static int number;
    private static class ReaderThread extends Thread {
            public void run() {
                while (!ready)
                    Thread.yield();
                System.out.println(number);
            }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ReaderThread().start();
        number = 42;
        ready = true;
    } 
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting this to print? And why?

Comment: @MickMnemonic The books says it may produce result as I said, it might also produce unexpected result like print 0 or never terminate. But when I check the book again, I find annotation remarks that without synchronization, JVM might cache values. It should be the reason.

Comment: You happen to see the desired result with high likelihood, because the code runs interpreted and the change to the variables is made before the second thread started executing the code. Add a delay before the write, to give the second thread a chance to execute its code and remove the `Thread.yield()` to raise the chance to get compiled, and voila, it does not terminate in time [“Time limit exceeded … 5s”](https://ideone.com/GRF0Md)…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `ready` isn't `volatile`, there's no guarantee that `ReaderThread` will see that your main thread has changed it. When you mark `ready` as volatile, all writes from one thread will be seen in other threads reading it.

You **always** need some sort of synchronization / visibility control when communicating between threads. Whether it's `volatile`, explicitly using `synchronized` or using the `java.util.concurrent.*` classes.

Comment: I see. If I don't use volatile or other synchronization, CPU might cache the value, which is the reason why **ReaderThread** can't read newest value, right?

Comment: Exactomundo. It's easy to see the caching in action in simple code like this, but in more complicated code it might **appear** to work correctly even without `volatile`. Then a different code path is taken and suddenly you've got a hard to find bug in your hands.

Comment: Sure. It's really dangerous to use Java Concurrency if I don't know the way JVM works. Thanks you~

Comment: @DiskunTsu it’s not only the CPU which may cache values, the JVM’s optimizer may transform the code to not re-read a value that is already known (from a single-threaded perspective). So if `ready` is not `volatile`, `while(!ready) Thread.yield();` may get optimized to `if(!ready) while(true) Thread.yield();` (or a simple *halt* CPU instruction, instead of the loop, if the target CPU has one).

Comment: @Hoger I see. Thanks~

Answer (score 3):

You don't need synchronization (e.g., `synchronized`) in your example (though you do need `volatile`, more below) because reads and writes of `boolean` and `int` variables are always atomic. Which is to say, a thread can't be *part-way* through writing to a `boolean` (or `int`) variable when another thread comes along and reads it, getting garbage. The value being written by one thread is always fully written before another thread can read it. (This is [**not** true](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.7) of non-`volatile` `double` or `long` variables; it would be entirely possible for a thread to read garbage if it happened to read in the middle of another thread's write to a `long` or `double` if they aren't marked `volatile`.)

But you do need `volatile`, because each thread can have its own copy of the variables, and potentially can keep using its own copy for a long period of time. So it's entirely possible for your reader thread to wait forever, because it keeps re-reading its own copy of `ready` which stays `false` even though your main thread writes `true` to *its* copy of `ready`. It's also possible for your reader thread to see `ready` become `true` but keep reading its own copy of `number`, and so print 0 instead of 42.

You would need to use `synchronized` if you were modifying the state of an object that doesn't guarantee thread-safe access. For instance, if you were adding to a `Map` or `List`. That's because there are multiple operations involved, and it's essential to prevent one thread from reading a half-complete change another thread is making.

Other classes, such as those in `java.util.concurrent`, offer classes with thread-safe access semantics.

Comment: Why does every thread has its own copy of the variables? Needn't I explicitly declare ThreadLocal for that? Or this is just a way which JVM uses to improve performance.

Comment: He's referring to a copy that's in a CPU cache, not a thread-local variable in the JVM.

Comment: @DiskunTsu - As Mick said, it may be cached by the CPU. I'm not 100% sure it may not also be cached by some runtime optimization path in the JVM. This is why we declare shared variables `volatile`, so we know they won't get cached (regardless of where). :-)

Comment: @MickMnemonic Yep

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Got it! Thanks~ BTW, it seems quite hard to control our CPU, but is there any trick I can use to get different result of the above code?

Comment: @DiskunTsu - If you start 3-4 threads reading `number` and make periodic updates to `number` from your main thread, you'll likely see caching at some point.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder But I think that's a different way. That kind of way error is due to Check-Then-Modify but not cache stuff.

Comment: @DiskunTsu - It depends on what you check for. But observing caching behavior may be difficult in a simple synthetic example in any case.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder runtime optimizations of the JVM are not only possible, they are the main reason to observe missing updates, especially for the x86/x64 architecture, where the CPU caches are invalidated if another CPU writes to the same address. By the way, there are only small changes necessary, to observe that behavior: https://ideone.com/GRF0Md

Comment: @Holger - Thanks! I thought so, but couldn't say it with assurance.

Comment: @Holger I did try it several times before. But it would finally terminate and output 42. It seems those two variables are not cached or somehow 'synchronized' in my laptop.

Comment: @DiskunTsu there is no guaranty to see wrong behavior when doing it wrong. There's only a guaranty to get the right behavior when doing it right…

Comment: @Holger Yep. I know that. Thank you all the same. But what I want to know is, in some tricky way, we can illustrate those wrong results.

Comment: @DiskunTsu well, I provided a link to Ideone with a modified version of your code which does reproducibly miss the variable update (note the “Time limit exceeded … 5s” message), [in my previous comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51669037/sharing-variable-without-synchronization/51669212?noredirect=1#comment90307622_51669212), but that’s just one environment. It may happen that the same program does not miss the update on your computer—or just occasionally.